# Some elements not displaying text with a font-face in OS X

Tags: ios, css, macos, font-face, font-family

There is an issue OS X where some elements are not displaying the text correctly, even though there are elements alongside it that do show.

Abbreviated example:

**Font-face declaration:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontFamily';
    src: src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;...);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

CSS

```
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li > a {
    font-family: "FontFamily", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Admin</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Outcome (missing home link above admin):

[image: Missing "Home" anchor]

A second example where a labels height is messed up but the text is visible within the label. Again renders correctly on non-OS X setups.

[image: Label loses height]

The link correctly renders in Chrome/Firefox/IE/Chrome Emulator but it does not render in OS X across all browsers (and iOS).

Comment: How do you know that it is an issue with the `font-face`/`font-family`?

Comment: I do not know! But I am using a custom don't so I figured I should mention it.

Comment: The typical behavior of a font that's not loading correctly is that you get a default font instead of the custom one. Can you provide a fiddle or [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) example showing the behavior?  Since the other link is showing up, and it has the same `font-family` rule applied to it, the issue is most likely something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the y-height was being setup in the font when being embedded (or something along those lines) with font squirrel. Changing the settings around on the vertical metrics option fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because you've got the link set to be coloured white on a white background?

```
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li > a {
    font-family: "FontFamily", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Try That :)

Or,

```
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li > a {
    font-family: "FontFamily", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: initial;
}
```

Comment: This is why making small examples never works :(. Fixed the color for the example.

Comment: Have you got a link to the page? :)

Answer (score 0):

After researching this I found that it shouldn't be an issue. However, I would suggest adding the full stack of different font file types. Typically, OTF and TTF are iOS friendly. For my sites, I use the following in order:

1. eot
2. svg
3. eot?#iefix
4. woff
5. ttf

This is just my preference and has been tested to work in all browsers/devices. I am sure someone can comment to say that other order may work for them.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for maximum compatibility, but you have to add all format:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a misspelling in your code:

you've typed "src:" twice

```
src: src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;...);
```

Maybe this code will work:

```
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;...);
```